# Group informations by code (linq group by?)

Tags: c#, api

Environment : -angular for the web app -c# for my api -sql server for the data base

I have this informations from my data base :

```html
public class Traductions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Lot { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string IdLangage { get; set; }
        public string LibelleLangage { get; set; }
        public string Traduction { get; set; }
    }
```

If i make a get with the api that return me that format Json informations :

```js
[
  {
  "Id": 1,
  "Lot" : 3,
  "Code" : "ABANDONDUTRAITEMENT",
  "Description" : "",
  "IdLangage": "FR",
  "LibelleLangage": "Francais",
  "Traduction": "Abandon du traitement"
  },
  {
  "Id": 2,
  "Lot" : 3,
  "Code" : "ABANDONDUTRAITEMENT",
  "Description" : "",
  "IdLangage": "EN",
  "LibelleLangage": "English",
  "Traduction": "Abandonment of       processing"
  }
  
]
```

But i want this type of Json format :

```js
[
  {
  "Code": "ABANDONDUTRAITEMENT",
  "FR": "Abandon du traitement",
  "EN": "Abandonment of processing"
  },
]
```

I want to group the informations by Code to return all the Translations (traduction) by Code.

I think i have to do it in my api and not in my angular application

How can i do it ? With linq group by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

somthing like this?

```
traductions.GroupBy(p => p.Code, 
                 (k, c) => new 
                         {
                             Code = k,
                             Data = c
                         }
                ).ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0

you can change the select to be how you want to represent the data in your angular application.

Comment: Where do i have to put it, in my Traductions class ?

Comment: you don't put it in your class, you put it at the end of your array, i made the assumption that your array is called traductions

Comment: That return me this error Traductions does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy'

Comment: make sure you have using System.Linq; at the top of you class.

Comment: The using System.Linq is here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/SSkiFV

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Maz6FY

Comment: This doesn't produce a result in the format OP needed, to the point that [they've asked the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615190/api-net-linq-group-by-transform-format-data)